# how to convert string to array in hive?

Tags: sql, arrays, split, hive, hiveql

The value of the column is like this:

```
["a", "b", "c(d, e)"]
```

Here the value is string type. I wish to convert the string to array, and I tried with `split (column_name, ',')`. However because the element in the array contains the comma symbol (e.g., `"c(d, e)"`), it didn't work well. Is there any other way to convert the string to array?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can split by comma only between double-quotas.

REGEXP `'(?<="), *(?=")'` matching comma with optional space only between `"` and `"`, not including quotas.

`(?<=")` is a zero-width lookbehind, asserts that what immediately precedes the current position in the string is "

`(?=")` is a zero-width positive lookahead assertion, means it should be " after current position

After splitting in such way, array will contain elements with quotes: '`"a"`', you may want to remove these quotes, use regexp_replace:

Demo:

```
with your_data as (
  select '["a", "b", "c(d, e)"]' as str
) 

select split(str, '(?<="), *(?=")')       as splitted_array, 
       element, 
       regexp_replace(element,'^"|"$','') as element_unquotted
  from (
        select regexp_replace(str,'^\\[|\\]$','') as str --remove square brackets
         from your_data 
       ) d
       --explode array   
       lateral view explode(split(str, '(?<="), *(?=")')) e as element
```

Result:

```
 splitted_array                       element      element_unquotted
 ["\"a\"","\"b\"","\"c(d, e)\""]       "a"          a
 ["\"a\"","\"b\"","\"c(d, e)\""]       "b"          b
 ["\"a\"","\"b\"","\"c(d, e)\""]       "c(d, e)"    c(d, e)
```

And if you need array of unquoted elements, you can collect array again using collect_list.

Another way is to replace ", " with some delimiter, remove all other quotas and square brackets, and split.

Demo:

```
with your_data as (
  select '["a", "b", "c(d, e)"]' as str
) 
select split(str,  '\\|\\|\\|') splitted_array 
  from (--replace '", ' with |||, remove all quotes, remove square brackets
         select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(str,'", *"','|||'),'^\\[|\\]$|"','') as str 
         from your_data ) d
```

Result:

```
splitted_array
["a","b","c(d, e)"]
```